# Nodal voltage analysis

Tags: voltage

Good afternoon. I was attempting to do a node analysis on the circuit and when I ran into a problem. Can you help me with it? How to calculate power dissipated in resistor using nodal analysis? 
[image: image of circuit]

Comment: You need to show your working - we are not a homework completion  service.

Comment: It might help if you rotate your picture - was that the problem you ran into?

Comment: ... and embed the photo into the question so that we don't have to follow the link.

Comment: ... and rotate the photo, so that I don't have to break my neck reading it. Or use the build-in schematic editor!

Answer (score 0):

Use nodal analysis to find the voltage across the resistor.

Then use what you know about resistors to find the current through the resistor.

Then use what you know about the relationship between voltage, current, and power to find the power dissipated by the resistor.

Nodal analysis is only the first step, it can't give the whole solution.